# Como posso otimizar meu código?

Tags: javascript, revisão-de-código

[image: Tabela]

Gostaria de otimizar meu código porém não sei como fazer. Ele tem que produzir um resultado tal como o da tabela acima.

Código:

```
    function calcular() {

        abiscissa = document.getElementById('ab').value;
        ordenada = document.getElementById('or').value;

        // Ordenada -1
        if (abiscissa == +3 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("210/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("210/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/150 \n160/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/200 \n160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/250 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/250 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -1) {
            alert("160/300 \n160/350");
        }

        // Ordenada -2
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("210/150");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("210/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("210/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/150 \n160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/200 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/200 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -2) {
            alert("160/250 \n150/350");
        }

        // Ordenada -3
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("160/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("160/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("160/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("160/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("160/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/200");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -3) {
            alert("210/300");
        }

        // Ordenada -4
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/250");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("120/150 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("120/150 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("120/150 \n160/300");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("120/250 \n160/350");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -4) {
            alert("120/250 \n160/350");
        }

        // Ordenada -5
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -5) {
            alert("");
        }

        // Ordenada -6
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -6) {
            alert("");
        }

        // Ordenada -7
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -7) {
            alert("");
        }

        // Ordenada -8
          else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +2 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == +1 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == 0 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -1 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -2 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -3 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -4 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -5 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -6 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -7 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        } else if (abiscissa == -8 && ordenada == -8) {
            alert("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Se puder informar o proposito do código daria para sugerir caminhos (fora exemplos de redução de ifs, afinal existe mais de uma maneira de otimizar e mais de um significado pra esta palavra).

Comment: O código é este mesmo? Parece inconsistente. Tentar fazer algo em cima de algo errado não vai dar, precisa ter certeza que é isto que deseja mesmo.

Comment: Estou tentando escrever uma resposta, mas vejo que sem saber exatamente o que você está fazendo, corro o risco de sugerir alguma otimização que você vai ter que desfazer depois, até porque o seu código está incompleto. Então, você pode dizer o que é que são esses números que você mostra nos alerts?

Comment: o codigo de esse falta apenas numeros dentro dos alertes do if e tipo uma tabela uma coluna e uma linha tipo linha -3 col -2 e um numero linha -3 col -1 e outro numero e assim vai

Comment: Qual que é a lógica/regra que define que o +3/-1 é "*160/150*" ao invés de ser "*210/200*" ou "*120/250 \n160/350*" ou "*laranja \n morango*"? O que faz os valores serem esses? É isso que precisamos saber para otimizar o seu código.

Comment: vou colocar uma imagem

Comment: Por que alguns locais têm dois valores? Quando só um deles está presente, faz alguma diferença ser só o primeiro ou só o segundo?

Comment: precisa seguir este padrão isso nao sou eu q estou definindo, os dois valores tem q aparecer

Comment: A imagem não clareou em nada a duvida, recomendo que leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, cada céllula é encontrada ao olhar a abscissa e a ordenada e pode ter até quatro números dentro dela. Que nome dou para esses quatro números que estão dentro de cada célula?

Comment: esses numeros eu usei um alert pra fazer como pd ver no codigo nao usei variaveis pra eles

Comment: jsfiddle.net/qdkha3nd/ talvez isso ajude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou usar uma abordagem de criar uma tabela JSON. Veja o código abaixo. Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> para testar.

```js
function formatarElemento(e) {
    return e.length === 2
        ? e[0].a + " / " + e[0].b + " - " + e[1].a + " / " + e[1].b
        : e[0].a + " / " + e[0].b;
}

function par(a, b) {
    return {"a": a, "b": b};
}

function celula1(par) {
    return [par];
}

function celula2(par1, par2) {
    return [par1, par2];
}

var tabela = {
    "-8": {
       "3": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "2": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "1": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "0": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-1": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-2": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 350)),
      "-8": celula2(par( 90, 250), par(160, 350))
    },
    "-7": {
       "3": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "2": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "1": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "0": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-1": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-2": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 350)),
      "-8": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(160, 350))
    },
    "-6": {
       "3": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "2": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "1": celula2(par( 90, 200), par(120, 300)),
       "0": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-1": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-2": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 300)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 350)),
      "-8": celula2(par( 90, 150), par(160, 350))
    },
    "-5": {
       "3": celula2(par( 90, 200), par( 90, 250)),
       "2": celula2(par( 90, 200), par( 90, 250)),
       "1": celula2(par( 90, 200), par( 90, 250)),
       "0": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 250)),
      "-1": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 250)),
      "-2": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 250)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 250)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 350)),
      "-8": celula2(par(120, 200), par(160, 350))
    },
    "-4": {
       "3": celula2(par( 90, 150), par( 90, 200)),
       "2": celula2(par( 90, 150), par( 90, 200)),
       "1": celula2(par( 90, 150), par( 90, 200)),
       "0": celula2(par(120, 150), par(120, 200)),
      "-1": celula2(par(120, 150), par(120, 200)),
      "-2": celula2(par(120, 200), par(120, 250)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 250)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 250)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 250)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 350)),
      "-8": celula2(par(120, 250), par(160, 350))
    },
    "-3": {
       "3": celula2(par( 90, 150), par( 90, 200)),
       "2": celula2(par( 90, 150), par( 90, 200)),
       "1": celula2(par( 90, 150), par( 90, 200)),
       "0": celula2(par(120, 150), par(120, 200)),
      "-1": celula2(par(120, 150), par(120, 200)),
      "-2": celula2(par(120, 150), par(120, 200)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 200)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 250)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 250)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 350)),
      "-8": celula1(               par(210, 300))
    },
    "-2": {
       "3": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
       "2": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
       "1": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
       "0": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
      "-1": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
      "-2": celula1(               par(160, 200)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 200)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 200)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 200)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 300)),
      "-8": celula2(par(160, 250), par(150, 350))
    },
    "-1": {
       "3": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
       "2": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
       "1": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
       "0": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
      "-1": celula1(               par(160, 150)),
      "-2": celula1(               par(160, 200)),
      "-3": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 200)),
      "-4": celula2(par(160, 150), par(160, 200)),
      "-5": celula2(par(160, 200), par(160, 250)),
      "-6": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 300)),
      "-7": celula2(par(160, 250), par(160, 300)),
      "-8": celula2(par(160, 300), par(160, 350))
    }
};

function calcular() {
    var abscissa = document.getElementById('ab').value;
    var ordenada = document.getElementById('or').value;
    if (abscissa < -8) abscissa = -8;
    if (ordenada < -8) ordenada = -8;
    var elemento = tabela["" + ordenada]["" + abscissa];
    document.getElementById('res').value = formatarElemento(elemento);
}
```

```html
<p>
    Abscissa (coluna da tabela): <input id="ab" type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    Ordenada (linha da tabela): <input id="or" type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="javascript: calcular();" />
</p>
<p>
    Resultado: <input id="res" type="text" readonly />
</p>
```

Chamei os elementos de cada par de `a` e `b`, pois não sabia como deveria nomeá-los. Para mudar isso, basta alterar os nomes nas funções `par` e `formatarElemento`.

Comment: ficou bom curti muito mas algo esta errado -8 -1 deveria dar 160/300 160/350 nao 160/250 160/350. Edit1: e so eu alterar vlw acho q esta melhor do que aquele bocado de if

Comment: @LucasSimao Apenas tinha copiado esse número errado. Já editei a resposta. Ainda tem que fazer o trabalho chato de verificar esses números todos um por um.

Comment: ok velho brigadao ficou mt menor e mais facil para compreender.

Comment: Como diriam, aqui tem coragem e dê o peixe não ensine a pescar :P ... só brincadeira, mas sinceramente você praticamente fez o trabalho todo, de qualquer forma ficou muito bom +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu ensinei a ele um outro modo de fazer que não fosse um monte de `if`s. Agora ele vai levar esse conhecimento consigo.